# error: incompatible types: com.example.sample.ListActivity cannot be converted to android.app.ListActivity

Tags: java, android, firebase

I keep getting this Error in my ListActivity.java

```
 public void deleteData(int index){
    pd.setTitle("Deleting data...");
    pd.show();
    db.collection("Documents").document(modelList.get(index).getId())
            .delete()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    showData();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            });
}
```

When i tried calling deleteData under customanother.java it cannot resolve method delete data in my ListActivity.java

Can someone help me to fix this? this is my first time in android studio to develop a simple crud app with firebase. My update, edit function works just fine but in my delete button idk why it cannot resolve the method.

heres my code in CustomAdapter.java

```
 public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(listActivity);
            String[] options = {"Update/Print", "Delete"};
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if ( which == 0){
                        String id = modelList.get(position).getId();
                        String title = modelList.get(position).getTitle();
                        String description = modelList.get(position).getDescription();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(listActivity, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("pId",id);
                        intent.putExtra("pTitle",title);
                        intent.putExtra("pDescription",description);
                        listActivity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if (which ==1){
                       listActivity.deleteData(position);
                    }

                }
            }).create().show();
        }
    });
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "it cannot resolve method delete"?

Comment: it cannot resolve the deleteData in here
if (which ==1){
                           listActivity.deleteData(position);
                        }

Answer (score 0):

Hello as mention in the error you try pass com.example.sample.ListActivity as android.app.ListActivity so the simple solution to change the import of your activity to become compatible

Comment: can you elaborate it?